# DataGridView с датами

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице есть столбец ДатаУстановкиПо Кол_воДнейЛицензии и ДатаОкончанияЛицензии.
Как сделать чтобы каждый раз при входе(В следующий день) вычитался один день из всего столбца КолВоДнейЛицензии. То есть сего осталось 12 дней до окончание, а если зайти завтра то будет 11, и так по всему столбцу.

Comment: дата окончания - сегодня в днях?

Comment: Вы поймите одну простую вещь. Все контролы, и DGV в частности, это такие "болванчики", их задача отображать данные или принимать от пользователя клики мышкой и клав.ввод. И это всё! Если вы хотите какие расчеты, и проч. обработку информации перед отображением, то она должна производится на стороне модели или БД. У вас что привязано к DGV таблица БД? Значит сделайте соотв. расчеты на стороне БД. Если привязана коллекция классов модели -- значит делайте расчеты в классе модели. И не надо бегать в цикле по клеткам в DGV и что-то там вычислять!